# Why is $2$ double root of the derivative?

Tags: calculus, derivatives, stationary-point

> A polynomial function $P(x)$ with degree $5$ increases in the interval
>   $(-\infty, 1)$ and $(3, \infty)$ and decreases in the interval
>   $(1,3)$. Given that $P'(2)= 0$ and $P(0) = 4$, find $P'(6)$.

In this problem, I have recognised that $2$ is an inflection point and the derivative will be of the form: $P'(x)= 5(x-1)(x-3)(x-2)(x-\alpha)$ .

But I am unable to *understand* why $x=2$ is double root of the derivative (i.e. why is $\alpha =2$?). It's not making sense to me. I need help with that part.

Comment: If $2$ was a single root then $P$ would switch to increasing at $x=2$.

Comment: why @copper.hat ...

Comment: Because $P'(2)=0$ and $P'$ has the form $P'(x) = (...)(x-2)(...)$, where the other parts keep the same sign close to $x=2$.

Comment: If $a$ were not $2$, then $P'$ would change sign at $2$ ... but we know $P'$ is negative on both sides of $2$.

Comment: Also, we know $P'$ has **at most** 4 roots, and we know two of them, so the only remaining options are a single or double root at $x=2$.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**HINT:**

If $2$ is an inflexion point then [it is necessary](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/InflectionPoint.html) that $P''(2)=0$, which means that you have a factor of $(x-2)^2$ in $P'(x)$.

Comment: How does factor of (x-2)^2 ensure that P''(2) = 0?

Comment: Differentiate $P'(x)$ and see what you get :)

Answer (score 4):

Since $2$ is an inflection point, we know that $P'(2)=0$ and $P''(2)=0$. (Convince yourself of this. What happens if $P''(2) \neq 0$?)

$P''(x)$ is then $-15ax^2 + 60ax - 55a + 20x^3 - 90x^2 + 110x - 30$. Plug in $2$ to get

$$P''(2) = 5 a - 10$$

And so $P''(2)$ is $0$ when $a=2$.

**EDIT:** [mechanodroid](https://math.stackexchange.com/users/144766/mechanodroid) gives us [a really clever shortcut](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2852767/why-is-2-double-root-of-the-derivative/2852773?noredirect=1#comment5883909_2852773):

> If $P′$ has a double root at $2$ then $P′(x)=(x−2)^2 Q(x)$. This immediately gives $P′(2)=0$. Differentiating $P′$ gives: $P″(x)=2(x−2)Q(x)+(x−2)^2 Q′(x)$
>   so $P″(2)=0$.

This means that knowing that $P'(2) = P''(2) = 0$ is sufficient to conclude that $(x-2)^2|P'(x)$, hence $\alpha=2$.

Answer (score 2):

**Hint:**

$2$ is an inflexion point so necessarily $P''(2) = 0$.

Now $P'(2) = P''(2) = 0$ so $2$ is a double root of $P'$.

Comment: It is true that $P'(x)$ must have a root at 2 and that $P''(x)$ must have a root at 2, but  how do we know these conditions are both satisfied when $P''(x)$ has a *double* root at $2$?

Comment: @TiwaAina If $P'$ has a double root at $2$ then $P'(x) = (x-2)^2Q(x)$. This immediately gives $P'(2) = 0$. Differentiating $P'$ gives:
$$P''(x) = 2(x-2)Q(x) + (x-2)^2Q'(x)$$
so $P''(2) = 0$.

Answer (score 1):

The fact that $x=2$ is an inflection point implies that the second derivative $P''(2)=0$ as well. That means $2$ should not just be a root of $P'$, but should still be a root if you take the derivative again. That is the case if it is a double root.

Comment: How do we know that a root is preserved (after differentiation) when it has multiplicity 2 or more? Especially when the polynomial has several roots?

Comment: By the power rule, the $(x-2)^2$ term will not disappear if you take the derivative, whereas $(x-2)$ (without the square) would.